# How to convert table data in XML format in java

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, apache-axis

I have one requirement. I have written a method in java which calls a method getEmpDetail, this method connect the SAP database and fetches employee details in console. I am using Eclipse kepler, apache tomcat 7.0.42 and axis2 1.6.2. I convert my method into web service(SOAP). When I run my web service in browser and call it displays the data in console. I want this all data in XML format in browser. I am working on struts with MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code available here

[How to convert table data in XML format in java](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html)